# How to use loop to count the number of nan

Tags: python, loops

There are a lot of stations in csv file, I don't know how to use loop to count the number of nan of every station. There is I got so far, count one by one. Can someone help me please, thank you in advance.

```
station1= train_df[train_df['station'] == 28079004]
station1 = station1[['date', 'O_3']]
count_nan = len(station1) - station1.count()
print(count_nan)
```

Comment: Ok, this is quite simple by using pandas `groupby` function. Are you familiar with it? In what column are the nans?

Comment: `np.sum(np.isnan(train_df['station']))`

Comment: @AntonvBR Actually, I have no idea how to use groupby function. In this exercise,  there are some nans in O_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need create index by `station` column with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), filter columns for check missing values and last count them by `sum`:

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'date':pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6),
                   'O_3':[np.nan,3,np.nan,9,2,np.nan],
                   'station':[28079004] * 2 + [28079005] * 4})

print (train_df)
   B  C       date  O_3   station
0  4  7 2015-01-01  NaN  28079004
1  5  8 2015-01-02  3.0  28079004
2  4  9 2015-01-03  NaN  28079005
3  5  4 2015-01-04  9.0  28079005
4  5  2 2015-01-05  2.0  28079005
5  4  3 2015-01-06  NaN  28079005

df = train_df.set_index('station')[['date', 'O_3']].isnull().sum(level=0).astype(int)
print (df)
          date  O_3
station            
28079004     0    1
28079005     0    2
```

Another solution:

```
df = train_df[['date', 'O_3']].isnull().groupby(train_df['station']).sum().astype(int)
print (df)
          date  O_3
station            
28079004     0    1
28079005     0    2
```

Comment: Yes this is quite smart! :D

Comment: @WangbeiShen - So need working with only one column `O_3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although jez already answered and that answer is probably better here. This is how a groupby would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(444)
n = 10

train_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'station': np.random.choice(np.arange(28079004,28079008), size=n),
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=n),
    'O_3': np.random.choice([np.nan,1], size=n)
})

print(train_df)

s = train_df.groupby('station')['O_3'].apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum())
print(s)
```

prints:

```
    station       date  O_3
0  28079007 2018-01-01  NaN
1  28079004 2018-01-02  1.0
2  28079007 2018-01-03  NaN
3  28079004 2018-01-04  NaN
4  28079007 2018-01-05  NaN
5  28079004 2018-01-06  1.0
6  28079007 2018-01-07  NaN
7  28079004 2018-01-08  NaN
8  28079006 2018-01-09  NaN
9  28079007 2018-01-10  1.0
```

And the output (s):

```
station
28079004    2
28079006    1
28079007    4
```